# Install system app fails

Tags: root-access, file-system, system-apps

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 which I have rooted. I am attempting to move app updates to `/system/app` to save space on my `/data/` partition. I follow the standard process (not enough points to link yet):

```
adb shell # start shell
$ su # elevate
$ mv /data/app/com.microsoft.skydrive-1 /system/app # move files to /system
$ chown -R root.root /system/app/com.microsoft.skydrive-1 # change owner
$ chmod 755 /system/app/com.microsoft.skydrive-1 # set permissions to match other system apps
$ chmod 644 /system/app/com.microsoft.skydrive-1/lib/arm/libpspdfkit.so # set lib permissions
$ mv /system/app/com.microsoft.skydrive-1/lib/arm/libpspdfkit.so /system/lib # move to system lib
$ chmod 755 /system/app/com.microsoft.skydrive-1/oat # set permissions to match other system apps
$ chmod 755 /system/app/com.microsoft.skydrive-1/oat/arm # set permissions to match other system apps
$ chmod 644 /system/app/com.microsoft.skydrive-1/oat/arm/base.odex # set permissions to match other system apps
$ chmod 644 /system/app/com.microsoft.skydrive-1/base.apk # set permissions to match other system apps
$ exit
$ exit
adb reboot
```

When the phone comes back on, the app is not found in the app list. Titanium Backup lists the app as uninstalled. If I reinstall the app from the Play Store it is added to `/data/app`.

I am using 6.0.1.

Comment: I'd suggest using an app like Titanium Backup to automate it.

Comment: Unfortunately TB seems to be suffering the same issue - it copies the apk to `/system/app` and removes the `/data/app` copy. But then... No app.

Comment: It is discouraged to place apps into **/system/app** . Place them into **/system/priv-app** , instead. You must also change their SELinux context.

Comment: Oh, really? Thank you for that. Is there some documentation I could read regarding this? It makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Apps in `priv-app` are (as the name implies) given extra privileges, which is probably not what you want for general apps.  It's not any more "discouraged" to place them in `/system/app/` than `/system/priv-app`.

Comment: What about the SELinux context? Or any idea why I and TB can't seem to move apps?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman on another post you recommended doing `u:object_r:system_file:s0 path_of_your_app.apk` in order to deal with the SELinux context. If I do a `ls -Z` on my apk and odex file they have `u:object_r:system_file:s0` listed already - but still no app.